# Significato di "farla lunga" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto questo dialogo tra Massimo, uno dei protagonisti del romanzo, e un suo amico fiorentino sulla spiaggia di Positano (grassetto mio):

> «E chi sarebbe *codesto*?» mi domandò il mio amico. 
>      
> «Un principe delle apparenze.» 
>      
> «Non fare il napoletano, che significa?» 
>      
> «Molto fascino e poche lire.» 
>      
> «Hai visto come la trattava?» 
>      
> «Prima la baci, poi la schiaffeggi e poi ti presenti. Era il suo sistema con questo tipo di ragazza. A quanto pare lo usa ancora.» 
>      
> «Finché può, finché può. Quella meritava più cura, con quel collo. Se fosse capitata a me una così...» 
>      
> «Tu non sei Sasà.» 
>      
> «Uuuh! Come **la fai lunga** con questo Sasà.» 
>      
> «E va bene, allora te la immagini una ragazza che si sveglia a quest’ora per raccogliere pietruzze di tormalina con te? Con te come sarai tra venti anni, all’età che ha ora lui.»

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lungo1) ho trovato la definizione seguente dell'espressione "farla lunga":

> Con compl. oggetto *la* indeterminato, nel linguaggio fam., *farla lunga*, allungare molto il discorso, insistere stucchevolmente nel chiedere, nel lamentarsi, nel protestare, nel rimproverare e sim.: *insomma, per non fartela tanto lunga, la cosa finì così*; *quanto la fai lunga!*

Tuttavia, questi due personaggi hanno parlato molto poco di questo Sasà, per cui non capisco quale sia il senso di questa locuzione nel contesto del brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Può essere che avessero parlato di Sasa in altre occasioni? L’espressione si usa anche se l’argomento in questione viene tirato in ballo in momenti e tempi diversi.

Comment: @Hachi:   Non credo che avessero parlato di Sasà precedentemente. Massimo aveva presentato Sasà all'amico fiorentino poco prima di questo dialogo, in cui questo amico gli chiede "E chi sarebbe *codesto*?", dando a intendere che non sa nulla di Sasà.

Comment: A volte, l’espressione si può usare anche quando la conversazione non è stata lunga, ma non si ha più voglia di parlare di quell'argomento. È come dire: «Non continuare a parlare di questo, non mi interessa».

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @Benedetta: è quasi come dire “Quanto rompi con questo Sasà”.

Comment: Potresti convertire il tuo commento in una risposta, per favore, @Benedetta?

Comment: Scrivo subito, @Charo. Se servono integrazioni, procedete pure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato figurato di *(non) farla lunga* è proprio quello già individuato nella domanda.

A volte, come nel brano riportato, l’espressione si può usare anche quando la conversazione non è stata lunga, ma non si ha più voglia di parlare di quell'argomento. È un modo per dire: «Non continuare a parlare di questo, non mi interessa».